# How to restrict mouse and graphics tablet to primary monitor?

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, macbook, graphics-tablet

I have a MacBook connected to a monitor as an extended display. I am using a wacom graphics tablet. I want to restrict the wacom to the primary display only and not move onto the secondary display.

The graphics tablet is small so using it across two display is difficult.

Can the same be done with a mouse?

Comment: The Wacom control panel can do this.  Can't provide a picture as mine's not connected right now